# Can't resolve snprintf warning in C

Tags: c, stm32, freertos, stm32cubeide

Facing a warning which I am not able to resolve. I am using stm32 MCU and STM32CubeIDE with a standard C11 compiler. I can easily get rid of the warning by increasing size of the array `gStr` but would like to know what is the issue here. Current size of `gStr` looks adequate to hold the given data.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

The global definitions of the variables used looks like this:

```
#define LOG_ERROR_FILENAME_MAX_LEN  30
#define LOG_ERROR_MAX_ENTRY 30
#define LOG_GSTR_SIZE   128     //changed from 128 to 2048 to remove warning

typedef struct
{
    char fileName[LOG_ERROR_FILENAME_MAX_LEN];
    u16 line;
    u16 hits;
} LogEntryType;

static LogEntryType gLogEntrys[LOG_ERROR_MAX_ENTRY];
u8 gLogEntryCount = 0;
static char gStr[LOG_GSTR_SIZE];
```

The function call where the warning is generated looks like this:

```
snprintf(gStr, LOG_GSTR_SIZE, "%s line:%u hits:%u",gLogEntrys[i].fileName, gLogEntrys[i].line, gLogEntrys[i].hits);
```

The `snprintf` call is generating the following warning

```
../User/Utils/log_error.c: In function 'cliCmdDisplayLog':
../User/Utils/log_error.c:54:36: **warning**: '%s' directive output may be truncated writing up to 1019 bytes into a region of size 128 [-Wformat-truncation=]
   54 |     snprintf(gStr, LOG_GSTR_SIZE, "%s line:%u hits:%u",
      |                                    ^~
../User/Utils/log_error.c:54:35: note: directive argument in the range [0, 65535]
   54 |     snprintf(gStr, LOG_GSTR_SIZE, "%s line:%u hits:%u",
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../User/Utils/log_error.c:54:35: note: directive argument in the range [1, 65535]
../User/Utils/log_error.c:54:5: note: 'snprintf' output between 15 and 1042 bytes into a destination of size 128
   54 |     snprintf(gStr, LOG_GSTR_SIZE, "%s line:%u hits:%u",
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   55 |      gLogEntrys[i].fileName, gLogEntrys[i].line, gLogEntrys[i].hits);
      |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Sure seems like a stupid warning to me - the entire **point** of using `snprintf()` is so the resulting string is truncated and doesn't overflow the buffer.  Frankly, I'd submit a bug report to the compiler vendor.  Might as well emit a warning for every integer addition or multiplication operation that it could overflow and invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I suppose it depends on whether or not the truncation is there to protect memory or as a "feature" of your program.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The entire point of `snprintf()` is to never write more than the specified number of `char`s to the buffer.  This warning amounts to "working as designed".

Comment: Seems like there's some static code analysis going on here.  *"note: 'snprintf' output between 15 and 1042 bytes into a destination of size 128"*

Comment: And yes, if the compiler is smart enough to figure that out, I'd definitely prefer to know about it.

Comment: I suspect that this may be [GCC bug 95755](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95755), or closely related to it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey 15 is the amount of chars it would write with 0s in the integers and empty string. I don't know from where the total of 1042 comes from (especially when the single string is limited to 30 bytes).

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: I read the about the subtle bug in the link. So the workaround would be something like `sprintf( format, ""%%.%us line:%%u hits:%%u", LOG_ERROR_FILENAME_MAX_LEN-1);` to prepare the format string according to the length written in the define and `snprintf(gStr, LOG_GSTR_SIZE, format,gLogEntrys[i].fileName, gLogEntrys[i].line, gLogEntrys[i].hits);` to actually print it? I leave the answer to you, @JonathanLeffler

Comment: It seems the compiler believes the `fileName` array is 1020 bytes long, and it assumes your file name could be as long as 1019 bytes as a result. The reason for 1020 appears to be from the fact that your `gLogEntries` array starting address is the same as the starting address of `gLogEntries[0].fileName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the symptoms, I think your problem is a variant of the problem reported to GCC as [GCC Bug 95755](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95755), reported in June 2020 but not yet fixed.

There is an outline workaround in the response to the report.  You would need to use limits in the format strings (`%*.*s` or `%.*s` with integers specifying the length), or you'd need to create the format string on the fly with one `snprintf()` operation creating the format string and a second using it.

Comment: YW — it cost me a few grey hairs identifying that.  I hope this spared you a few.